# Tunnel to access internet

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

There is a central server `A` that doesn't have internet access. I am supposed to log in to a server `B` (that has an internet connection) and launch jobs on `A`. I wonder if I can create a tunnel from `A` to `B` to connect to the internet. There is information that I want to monitor while the jobs are running, and it can only happen if I send that information to a web service that I am currently using.

What should the command be so that the packets are correctly tunneled from `A` to `B` to the internet?

Comment: Do you want to ssh to B directly or do you want to expose some other port?

Comment: I ssh to `B` all the time.